# Issue with Selenium function to select a specific article in a Tree component using dynamic XPath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to create a Selenium function that will select a specific article in a Tree component. This article was already searched for in the corresponding searchbar. So it is the only element that is present.

I am trying to create the xPath for this element dynamically based on the ArticleId.

I know there are more simpler methods to select an element e.g. with `By.className`, `By.Id`, etc. ... but unfortunately this always selects the same element and does not work in my UseCase. So I try to select the element with the corresponding ArticleId.

My xPath looks like this: `//span[contains(text(), 'articleId')]`

The problem is that my test case does not find this element. But when I manually search for it in the FireFox console it works.

Heres my function:

```
public void selectArticleWithSpecificArticleNr(String article) {
    WebElement correspondingArticle = waitTime.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), '" + article + "')]"))));
    correspondingArticle.click();
}
```

That would be the span element as it is in the DOM:

```
<span _ngcontent-ewt-c164="" style="font-size: 13px; display: block; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: initial;" class="ng-star-inserted"> 10225929 </span>
```

I already tried to wait for a while before clicking on this element with `Thread.sleep(ms)`, because maybe the element has not been present in the DOM yet. But that didn't work either.

The funny thing is that the first time I tried to run this test, the function found the element. But after I tried it again and again it didn't.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: `waitTime` an instance variable? How is it defined?

Comment: `waitTime` is defined in my contructor as `WebDriverWait`.

 `public StorageModulePage(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait waitTime) {
  this.driver = driver;
  this.waitTime = waitTime;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<span _ngcontent-ewt-c164="" style="font-size: 13px; display: block; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: initial;" class="ng-star-inserted"> 10225929 </span>
```

You can modify the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) as follows:

```
public void selectArticleWithSpecificArticleNr(String article) {
    WebElement correspondingArticle = waitTime.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(., '" + article + "')]"))));
    correspondingArticle.click();
}
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work ... i get this error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on windows ('ID'] -> xpath: //span[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(., '10217672')]] (tried for 7 second(s) with 200 milliseconds interval)`

Comment: @stax Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.